# Different layouts and routes on single views for a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and have a question regarding layouts and routing in a CMS. I haven't come across an answer on this particular issue after searching the web so I hope someone here could help me.

I'm building a CMS and have to layouts, *application.html.erb* (default) which is the front public page and *admin.html.erb* which is available after logging in.

I have resource called *Post*. Is it possible that only the show view uses the default layout while the rest of the views uses the admin layout?

In other words I want urls to single posts to be like "myAppDomain/posts/1" and use the default layout
while administrative views should have */admin* as a prefix and use the admin layout,
like "myAppDomain/admin/posts", "myAppDomain/admin/posts/1/edit"

Now I've set up a route that "adds" the /admin to the posts urls

```
scope "/admin" do
   resources :posts
end
```

And in the PostsController I specify to use the admin layout

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authorize , :except => [:show]
   layout 'admin'
   ...
```

So now people can read posts without logging in, but the links to the single post view on my welcome page is rendered "myAppDomain/admin/posts/1" and it uses the admin layout

```
<%= link_to post.title, post %>
```

Is there a way to use different layouts and routes on single views for a resource or should I go for a different approach?

Answer (score 5):

Just specify the layout in the action

```
def show
    render :layout => 'application'    
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a before_action

```
private

def layout_set
  if current_user.admin?
    layout 'admin'
  else
    layout 'default'
  end
end
```

At the top of the controller:

```
before_action :layout_set
```

Now you can forget about adding the layout. You can take it a step further and put the before action in your application controller and you can add that functionality in all your controllers by just adding the same before_action. You save a lot of extra code this way.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here looking for how to have no layout at all. In case anyone else is after that, use `render layout: false`:

```rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def your_action
    # your code here

    render layout: false
  end
end
```